# How do I use the `--directory` flag of KRun

Tags: kframework

I've compiled a K definition using `kompile foo.k`.

However, when I run `krun --directory foo-kompiled/ my-program.foo` I see the following error:

```
[Error] Critical: Could not find a compiled definition. Use --directory to specify one.
```

How do I correctly use this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical reasons, `kompile --directory . foo.k` creates a directory `foo-kompiled` underneath `.` rather than using `.` as the output directory itself. Similarly, `krun` and other tools that use a compiled k definition look for a directory matching the glob `*-kompiled` within the directory passed by `--directory`. Thus, if you run `kompile foo.k` the correct invocation for krun (since the default value of --directory is the current working directory) is `krun my-program.foo --directory .`, or simply `krun my-program.foo`